# Finding the number of palindromic sequences from a given set of numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, palindrome

Suppose we are given a set of numbers like 20 40 20 60 80 60
It can be broken up into 2 palindromic sequences: `20 40 20`, and `60 80 60`.
It can also be broken into 6 palindromic sequences each containing a single number.

How do we find the smallest number of palindromic sequences possible from a given set of numbers in c++?

PS- This is not my homework. Genuine question.

Comment: Please show us what you have done, at least some ideas in your mind.

Comment: @aga_pan I thought of finding the number of times a particular number is repeated and finding all the possible palindromes. But now i dont know how to go about it.

Comment: @yash.cr7: In the example you give above, did you type `20 40 60 20 80 60` correctly, or is it meant to be `20 40 20 60 80 60`? I'm trying to understand whether you're looking for strictly consecutive subsequences or whether you allow non-consecutive subsequences as well.

Comment: @MichaelLaszlo sorry, my mistake. I've edited my question. They're supposed to be consecutive.

Comment: Very good, thank you. You have enough reputation now to upvote answers, by the way.

Comment: I did that already @MichaelLaszlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A straightforward approach begins by looking at each of the O(n<sup>3</sup>) subsequences and checking to see if it's a palindrome. Once we know which subsequences are palindromic, we can do dynamic programming in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time to find the minimal number of consecutive subsequences that cover the whole sequence.

For the input `20 40 20 60 80 60`, the C++ implementation below prints `[20 40 20] [60 80 60]`.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  // Read the data from standard input.
  vector<int> data;
  int x;
  while (scanf("%d", &x) != EOF) {
    data.push_back(x);
  }
  int n = data.size();

  // Look at every subsequence and determine if it's a palindrome.
  vector<vector<bool> > is_palindrome(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    is_palindrome[i] = vector<bool>(n);
    for (int j = i; j < n; ++j) {
      bool okay = true;
      for (int left = i, right = j; left < right; ++left, --right) {
        if (data[left] != data[right]) { 
          okay = false;
          break; 
        }
      }
      is_palindrome[i][j] = okay;
    }
  }

  // Dynamic programming to find the minimal number of subsequences.
  vector<pair<int,int> > best(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    // Check for the easy case consisting of one subsequence.
    if (is_palindrome[0][i]) {
      best[i] = make_pair(1, -1);
      continue;
    }
    // Otherwise, make an initial guess from the last computed value.
    best[i] = make_pair(best[i-1].first + 1, i-1);
    // Look at earlier values to see if we can improve our guess.
    for (int j = i-2; j >= 0; --j) {
      if (is_palindrome[j+1][i]) {
        if (best[j].first + 1 < best[i].first) {
          best[i].first = best[j].first + 1;
          best[i].second = j;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Minimal partition: %d sequences\n", best[n-1].first);
  vector<int> indices;
  int pos = n-1;
  while (pos >= 0) {
    indices.push_back(pos);
    pos = best[pos].second;
  }
  pos = 0;
  while (!indices.empty()) {
    printf("[%d", data[pos]);
    for (int i = pos+1; i <= indices.back(); ++i) {
      printf(" %d", data[i]);
    }
    printf("] ");
    pos = indices.back()+1;
    indices.pop_back();
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have argue that this is not the answer for this question. He is not asking the minimal number of palindromic substring. As subsequence is not necessarily consecutive, this approach does not work.

Comment: Where did the word "consecutive" come from? He never said the sequences are consecutive and his example clearly showed that.

Comment: I assumed that he had mistyped the example and was actually looking for consecutive palindromes. The problem becomes quite a bit harder if you allow non-consecutive palindromes. It isn't clear to me that it can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: @aga_pan: Now that the question has been amended to indicate that the subsequences are indeed consecutive, do you mind reversing your downvote?

Comment: I will reverse my downvote once it's unlocked. Yes, I don't think the original question can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: It seems my vote is locked unless you edit your answer. Do you mind just edit some words in your answer so that I can reverse my vote?

Comment: @aga_pan: Gladly. Done.